# Creating network scanner using python

Tags: python, scapy

I has to build a ARP request program using python

```
import scapy.all as scapy
def scan(ip):
    arp_request = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
    print(arp_request.summary())

scan("192.168.1.1/24")
```

The result is

```
ARP who has ?? says ??
```

Please help me.

**And Thank you!**

Comment: I am a bit lost - like what is the intended behavior here?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
scan("192.168.1.1/24")
```

to:

```
scan("192.168.1.1")
```